# Modify the powershell script to add additional parameter

Tags: powershell

the below script was created by our pervious IT guy, what this script does is basically replaces the Funduc Software (RSP and RSBE) config file in the logged in user's Appdata so we can modify what the software will search over. E.g. Excel Word etc.

I need to modify this script in such a way that it when ran without any parameter provided it runs as it but if we specify a parameter it automatically runs the config we need.

Right now if we run `.\RSUpdateConfigFile.ps1` it starts the script and waits for user to enter a number which corresponds to the extensions we need to search over, this works fine as is.

What we'd like it to do is if we run `.\RSUpdateConfigFile.ps1 -L_V_1_String_PreSelection 10` it should execute the script and without prompting the user automatically update the config file with Word extensions.

Below is the code we are using. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
Param(
    $L_V_1_String_DisplayComputerName = $env:ComputerName,
    $L_V_1_String_DestinationPath = $env:APPDATA,
    $L_V_Array_String_ConfigurationFilesToCopy = @(
        "A:\Input\Replace Studio.cfg",
        "A:\Input\Replace Studio Business Edition.cfg"
    ),  
    $L_V_HashTable_String_FileExtensions = [Ordered] @{
        "All                                                       files" = "*.*";
        "All Excel, PowerPoint, Visio, and Word                    files" = "*.xlm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xlsm;*.xltm;*.xlsx;*.xltx;*.ppt;*.pps;*.pot;*.pptm;*.ppsm;*.potm;*.pptx;*.ppsx;*.potx;*.vsl;*.vsd;*.vsdx;*.vsdm;*.vssm;*.vstm;*.vssx;*.vstx;*.vss;*.vtt;*.vsw;*.vdx;*.vsx;*.vtx;*.doc;*.dot;*.docm;*.dotm;*.docx;*.dotx";
        "All Excel, PowerPoint, Visio, and Word internal           files" = "*_A_I_*.xlm;*_A_I_*.xls;*_A_I_*.xlt;*_A_I_*.xlsm;*_A_I_*.xltm;*_A_I_*.xlsx;*_A_I_*.xltx;*_A_I_*.ppt;*_A_I_*.pps;*_A_I_*.pot;*_A_I_*.pptm;*_A_I_*.ppsm;*_A_I_*.potm;*_A_I_*.pptx;*_A_I_*.ppsx;*_A_I_*.potx;*_A_I_*.vsl;*_A_I_*.vsd;*_A_I_*.vsdx;*_A_I_*.vsdm;*_A_I_*.vssm;*_A_I_*.vstm;*_A_I_*.vssx;*_A_I_*.vstx;*_A_I_*.vss;*_A_I_*.vtt;*_A_I_*.vsw;*_A_I_*.vdx;*_A_I_*.vsx;*_A_I_*.vtx;*_A_I_*.doc;*_A_I_*.dot;*_A_I_*.docm;*_A_I_*.dotm;*_A_I_*.docx;*_A_I_*.dotx";
        "All Excel                                                 files" = "*.xlm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xlsm;*.xltm;*.xlsx;*.xltx";
        "All Excel                              internal           files" = "*_A_I_*.xlm;*_A_I_*.xls;*_A_I_*.xlt;*_A_I_*.xlsm;*_A_I_*.xltm;*_A_I_*.xlsx;*_A_I_*.xltx";
        "All PowerPoint                                            files" = "*.ppt;*.pps;*.pot;*.pptm;*.ppsm;*.potm;*.pptx;*.ppsx;*.potx";
        "All PowerPoint                         internal           files" = "*_A_I_*.ppt;*_A_I_*.pps;*_A_I_*.pot;*_A_I_*.pptm;*_A_I_*.ppsm;*_A_I_*.potm;*_A_I_*.pptx;*_A_I_*.ppsx;*_A_I_*.potx";
        "All Visio                                                 files" = "*.vsl;*.vsd;*.vsdx;*.vsdm;*.vssm;*.vstm;*.vssx;*.vstx;*.vss;*.vtt;*.vsw;*.vdx;*.vsx;*.vtx";
        "All Visio                              internal           files" = "*_A_I_*.vsl;*_A_I_*.vsd;*_A_I_*.vsdx;*_A_I_*.vsdm;*_A_I_*.vssm;*_A_I_*.vstm;*_A_I_*.vssx;*_A_I_*.vstx;*_A_I_*.vss;*_A_I_*.vtt;*_A_I_*.vsw;*_A_I_*.vdx;*_A_I_*.vsx;*_A_I_*.vtx";
        "All Word                                                  files" = "*.doc;*.dot;*.docm;*.dotm;*.docx;*.dotx";
        "All Word                               internal           files" = "*_A_I_*.doc;*_A_I_*.dot;*_A_I_*.docm;*_A_I_*.dotm;*_A_I_*.docx;*_A_I_*.dotx";
        "All Word                                        agreement files" = "*_A_*.doc;*_A_*.dot;*_A_*.docm;*_A_*.dotm;*_A_*.docx;*_A_*.dotx"
        "All Word                                        form      files" = "*_F_*.doc;*_F_*.dot;*_F_*.docm;*_F_*.dotm;*_F_*.docx;*_F_*.dotx"
        "All Word                                        letter    files" = "*_L_*.doc;*_L_*.dot;*_L_*.docm;*_L_*.dotm;*_L_*.docx;*_L_*.dotx"
    },
    $L_V_1_String_Placeholder = "%Placeholder%"
)
Clear-Host
$L_V_1_Integer_Index = 0
$L_V_1_String_Prompt = "Enter the number representing your desired option:`n`n"
foreach ($L_V_1_String_Key in ($L_V_HashTable_String_FileExtensions.Keys))
{
    $L_V_1_String_Prompt += "$L_V_1_Integer_Index) "+$L_V_1_String_Key+"`n`n"
    $L_V_1_Integer_Index += 1
}
Try
{
    $L_V_1_String_UserSelection = Read-Host -Prompt $L_V_1_String_Prompt
    if (($L_V_1_String_UserSelection -eq $null) -or (-not($L_V_1_String_UserSelection  -match "\d")))
    {
        Throw
    }
    else
    {
        Try
        {
            #Replace placeholders, and save files to destination.
            foreach($L_V_1_String_ConfigurationFileToCopy in $L_V_Array_String_ConfigurationFilesToCopy)
            {
                $L_V_1_FileInfo_ConfigurationFileToCopy = [io.FileInfo] $L_V_1_String_ConfigurationFileToCopy
                $L_V_1_DestinationFilePath = "$L_V_1_String_DestinationPath\"+$L_V_1_FileInfo_ConfigurationFileToCopy.Name
                Get-Content $L_V_1_FileInfo_ConfigurationFileToCopy -ErrorAction Stop | Foreach-Object {$_.replace($L_V_1_String_Placeholder , $L_V_HashTable_String_FileExtensions[[int]$L_V_1_String_UserSelection])} | Set-Content -Path $L_V_1_DestinationFilePath -ErrorAction Stop   
                Write-Host "File '$L_V_1_DestinationFilePath' has been copied!"
            }
        }
        Catch
        {
            Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
            Exit 1
        }
    }
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host "That is not a valid choice!"
    Exit 1
}
Write-Host "ComputerName: $L_V_1_String_DisplayComputerName"
Pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added your parameter to the script, it should only prompt you when not provided:

```
Param(
    $L_V_1_String_DisplayComputerName = $env:ComputerName,
    $L_V_1_String_DestinationPath = $env:APPDATA,
    $L_V_Array_String_ConfigurationFilesToCopy = @(
        "A:\Input\Replace Studio.cfg",
        "A:\Input\Replace Studio Business Edition.cfg"
    ),  
    $L_V_HashTable_String_FileExtensions = [Ordered] @{
        "All                                                       files" = "*.*";
        "All Excel, PowerPoint, Visio, and Word                    files" = "*.xlm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xlsm;*.xltm;*.xlsx;*.xltx;*.ppt;*.pps;*.pot;*.pptm;*.ppsm;*.potm;*.pptx;*.ppsx;*.potx;*.vsl;*.vsd;*.vsdx;*.vsdm;*.vssm;*.vstm;*.vssx;*.vstx;*.vss;*.vtt;*.vsw;*.vdx;*.vsx;*.vtx;*.doc;*.dot;*.docm;*.dotm;*.docx;*.dotx";
        "All Excel, PowerPoint, Visio, and Word internal           files" = "*_A_I_*.xlm;*_A_I_*.xls;*_A_I_*.xlt;*_A_I_*.xlsm;*_A_I_*.xltm;*_A_I_*.xlsx;*_A_I_*.xltx;*_A_I_*.ppt;*_A_I_*.pps;*_A_I_*.pot;*_A_I_*.pptm;*_A_I_*.ppsm;*_A_I_*.potm;*_A_I_*.pptx;*_A_I_*.ppsx;*_A_I_*.potx;*_A_I_*.vsl;*_A_I_*.vsd;*_A_I_*.vsdx;*_A_I_*.vsdm;*_A_I_*.vssm;*_A_I_*.vstm;*_A_I_*.vssx;*_A_I_*.vstx;*_A_I_*.vss;*_A_I_*.vtt;*_A_I_*.vsw;*_A_I_*.vdx;*_A_I_*.vsx;*_A_I_*.vtx;*_A_I_*.doc;*_A_I_*.dot;*_A_I_*.docm;*_A_I_*.dotm;*_A_I_*.docx;*_A_I_*.dotx";
        "All Excel                                                 files" = "*.xlm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xlsm;*.xltm;*.xlsx;*.xltx";
        "All Excel                              internal           files" = "*_A_I_*.xlm;*_A_I_*.xls;*_A_I_*.xlt;*_A_I_*.xlsm;*_A_I_*.xltm;*_A_I_*.xlsx;*_A_I_*.xltx";
        "All PowerPoint                                            files" = "*.ppt;*.pps;*.pot;*.pptm;*.ppsm;*.potm;*.pptx;*.ppsx;*.potx";
        "All PowerPoint                         internal           files" = "*_A_I_*.ppt;*_A_I_*.pps;*_A_I_*.pot;*_A_I_*.pptm;*_A_I_*.ppsm;*_A_I_*.potm;*_A_I_*.pptx;*_A_I_*.ppsx;*_A_I_*.potx";
        "All Visio                                                 files" = "*.vsl;*.vsd;*.vsdx;*.vsdm;*.vssm;*.vstm;*.vssx;*.vstx;*.vss;*.vtt;*.vsw;*.vdx;*.vsx;*.vtx";
        "All Visio                              internal           files" = "*_A_I_*.vsl;*_A_I_*.vsd;*_A_I_*.vsdx;*_A_I_*.vsdm;*_A_I_*.vssm;*_A_I_*.vstm;*_A_I_*.vssx;*_A_I_*.vstx;*_A_I_*.vss;*_A_I_*.vtt;*_A_I_*.vsw;*_A_I_*.vdx;*_A_I_*.vsx;*_A_I_*.vtx";
        "All Word                                                  files" = "*.doc;*.dot;*.docm;*.dotm;*.docx;*.dotx";
        "All Word                               internal           files" = "*_A_I_*.doc;*_A_I_*.dot;*_A_I_*.docm;*_A_I_*.dotm;*_A_I_*.docx;*_A_I_*.dotx";
        "All Word                                        agreement files" = "*_A_*.doc;*_A_*.dot;*_A_*.docm;*_A_*.dotm;*_A_*.docx;*_A_*.dotx"
        "All Word                                        form      files" = "*_F_*.doc;*_F_*.dot;*_F_*.docm;*_F_*.dotm;*_F_*.docx;*_F_*.dotx"
        "All Word                                        letter    files" = "*_L_*.doc;*_L_*.dot;*_L_*.docm;*_L_*.dotm;*_L_*.docx;*_L_*.dotx"
    },
    $L_V_1_String_Placeholder = "%Placeholder%",
    $L_V_1_String_PreSelection
)
Clear-Host
$L_V_1_Integer_Index = 0
$L_V_1_String_Prompt = "Enter the number representing your desired option:`n`n"
foreach ($L_V_1_String_Key in ($L_V_HashTable_String_FileExtensions.Keys))
{
    $L_V_1_String_Prompt += "$L_V_1_Integer_Index) "+$L_V_1_String_Key+"`n`n"
    $L_V_1_Integer_Index += 1
}
Try
{
    if ($L_V_1_String_PreSelection){
        $L_V_1_String_UserSelection = $L_V_1_String_PreSelection
    } else {
        $L_V_1_String_UserSelection = Read-Host -Prompt $L_V_1_String_Prompt
    } 
        
    if (($L_V_1_String_UserSelection -eq $null) -or (-not($L_V_1_String_UserSelection  -match "\d")))
    {
        Throw
    }
    else
    {
        Try
        {
            #Replace placeholders, and save files to destination.
            foreach($L_V_1_String_ConfigurationFileToCopy in $L_V_Array_String_ConfigurationFilesToCopy)
            {
                $L_V_1_FileInfo_ConfigurationFileToCopy = [io.FileInfo] $L_V_1_String_ConfigurationFileToCopy
                $L_V_1_DestinationFilePath = "$L_V_1_String_DestinationPath\"+$L_V_1_FileInfo_ConfigurationFileToCopy.Name
                Get-Content $L_V_1_FileInfo_ConfigurationFileToCopy -ErrorAction Stop | Foreach-Object {$_.replace($L_V_1_String_Placeholder , $L_V_HashTable_String_FileExtensions[[int]$L_V_1_String_UserSelection])} | Set-Content -Path $L_V_1_DestinationFilePath -ErrorAction Stop   
                Write-Host "File '$L_V_1_DestinationFilePath' has been copied!"
            }
        }
        Catch
        {
            Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
            Exit 1
        }
    }
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host "That is not a valid choice!"
    Exit 1
}
Write-Host "ComputerName: $L_V_1_String_DisplayComputerName"
Pause
```